# How would I ago about creating an application that runs 24/7 and sends emails?

Tags: python-3.x, web-applications, python-requests, server-side

I have created this console script with python3 that uses the `requests` module to pull information from the website https://api.warframestat.us/ps4/fissures but I want to run this 24/7 and not on my computer is it possible to do this computation online? My program executes itself every minute because the website changes its information. I'm new to programming by the way, I know my questions are for some of you trivial.

I have not added the ability to send emails, I will do that later.

My code:

```
import JSON
import requests
import time



url = 'https://api.warframestat.us/ps4/fissures'
current_survivals = [] # hold current survivals until new once appear
ids_sent = []

while True:
    raw_data = requests.get(url)
    fissures_data = json.loads(raw_data.text)

    # I have to clear to get rid of the old id's
    current_survivals.clear()

    print()
    for x in fissures_data:
        print(x['missionType'])
    print()
    # add 
    for mission in fissures_data:
        if mission['missionType'] == 'Capture':
            # add to current_survivals
            current_survivals.append(mission['id'])

    # Makes sure not to send an email twice 
    for x in current_survivals:
        if x in ids_sent:
            print("Email already sent.")
        else:
            ids_sent.append(x)
            print("Send Email")

            # send an email 

    print("Current_survivals: " + str(current_survivals))
    print("ids_sent: " + str(ids_sent) + "\n")


    time.sleep(60) #will run agian after 1 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it a) not run on your computer and b) run every minute, perhaps the best approach would be to use an AWS lambda (or equiv on Azure etc).

You'd need to set an AWS account, config a lambda etc etc - so a bit of a learning curve there, but it does seem to be the cleanest way to do it.

The other approach would be a cloud server (eg AWS server instance), but to have it run every minute you'd then be having to deal with (and learn) cron, or have your code sleep for a minute then try.  But in that case you'd also need to worry about uptime, and some system to ensure your script is working correctly, being launched correctly etc etc.

Comment: Thank you Richard, I have looked into AWS and have created an account it does look a bit confusing but still thank you for help.

Comment: It is confusing - no way around that.  But there are some pretty good guides etc if you hunt around on google.